# Sorting through Data

Tags: python, function

This is similar to an example from a book I'm learning to code from. I have a single function that I would like to have the input data sorted according to the parameters of the "for" construction but it doesn't sort out the data. What am I doing wrong? I'm learning so be gentle! :)

```
def sort_high_to_low(user_prompt="Please enter the amount of stands you want to enter sales for: "):
    user_input = int(input(user_prompt))

    for count in range(1, user_input + 1):
        prompt = "Please enter the sales for stand " + str(count) + ": "
        sales.append(read_int(prompt))


    print(sales)


    for sort_pass in range(0, len(sales)):
        for count1 in range(0, len(sales)-1):
            if sales[count1] < sales[count1 + 1]:
                temp = sales[count1]
                sales[count1] = sales[count1+1]
                sales[count1+1] = temp

sort_high_to_low()
```

Comment: intiate sales =[] before the for loop

Comment: read_int will not work as you want, think about reusing the same idea as you had used earlier: int(input(prompt))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code works:

```
def sort_high_to_low(user_prompt="Please enter the amount of stands you want to enter sales for: "):
    user_input = int(input(user_prompt))
    print(user_input)
    sales = []
    for count in range(1, user_input + 1):
        prompt = "Please enter the sales for stand " + str(count) + ": "
        sales.append(int(input(prompt)))

    print(sales)
    print(sorted(sales))
sort_high_to_low()
```

Comment: not exactly, since what i guess the OP wanted was entries separated with spaces and not newlines on input

Answer (score 1):

You need to either first initialize `sales` as an empty list in the beginning of function and `return sales` at the end, or initialize `sales` globally as an empty list.

`sales = []`

And why won't you use `sales.sort()` in place of the nested for-loops sorting algorithm?

There was a comment about `read_int` not going to work… use

```py
int(i) for i in input(prompt).split()
```

instead, if you want many entries on one line

Comment: I have never encountered the sales.sort() statement in my book. I have no idea how it works. The book provides these types of examples.